# Keep the value selected after fetching the data and query to insert it into database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this onchange event on php, if the user choose an option, it fetched the data that is connected on it. However, the page refreshes and the choice of the user disappear. Also, I cannot insert the data to database. I've tried add a form method="post" to the form attribute, but unfortunately it cannot fetch the data.

Thankyou in advance.

```
  <?php

  $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=admin';
  $username = 'root';
 $password = '';

  try{
// Connect To MySQL Database
$con = new PDO($dsn,$username,$password);
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (Exception $ex) {

echo 'Not Connected '.$ex->getMessage();

}

$gradeassign = '';
$sectionassign = '';

 function getPosts()
 {
  $posts = array();

$posts[3] = $_POST['sectionassign'];
$posts[4] = $_POST['gradeassign'];

return $posts;
}

if(isset($_POST['addfac']))
{
$data = getPosts();

    $insertStmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO     
   facultyagain(sectionnumber,gradelevelassign) 
   VALUES(:sectionassign,:gradeassign)');
    $insertStmt->execute(array(
                ':sectionassign'=> $data[3],
                ':gradeassign'=> $data[4],
    ));

    if($insertStmt)
    {
            echo 'Data Inserted';
    }

       }


       ?>

            <html>
          <head>
          <title>Country</title>
       </head>
       <body>

       <form action="trial.php">
       Select Your grade
       <select name="gradeassign" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="" disabled selected>--select--</option>
    <option value="1">Grade 1</option>
    <option value="2">Grade  2</option>
    <option value="europe">Europe</option>
       </select>

       <?php
       require 'connection.php'; 
          if(isset($_GET["gradeassign"])){
          $gradeassign=$_GET["gradeassign"];

         $sql = "SELECT sectionassign FROM sections WHERE        gradeassign='$gradeassign'";
         $result = $con->query($sql);

       echo "<select>";
     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo "<option value='$row[sectionassign]'>" . $row["sectionassign"]. "               </option>";
       }
       } else { echo "<B>0 Results</B>"; }
       echo "</select>";
   }
       ?>
       <BR>
       <button id="addfac" name="addfac">Add Faculty</button>
       </form>

   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I think you can store the data / selected option in a session or a cookie and use it.

Comment: Wait, I don't have a background in doing so. Please kindly help me. Thanks

Comment: You can store the data in a session using `$_SESSION['session_name'] = $_POST['your_selectbox_name'];` and then use it near your select box options like `<option value="value_here" <?php if($_SESSION['session_name'] == 'value_here'){echo 'selected';}?>>Something's Value</option>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also store the value in a variable and check to see if the option matches the variable. For example:

```
 <option value="" disabled>--select--</option>
<option value="1" <?php if(isset($_GET['gradeassign'])) && $_GET['gradeassign'] == "1") echo "checked"; ?>>Grade 1</option>
<option value="2" <?php if(isset($_GET['gradeassign'])) && $_GET['gradeassign'] == "2") echo "checked"; ?>>Grade  2</option>
<option value="europe" <?php if(isset($_GET['gradeassign'])) && $_GET['gradeassign'] == "europe") echo "checked"; ?>>Europe</option>
```

The better way to do it would be to create the whole list with a loop. Bu this should work.